# Radio button values in Bootstrap and AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I Have radio button as

```
<tr>
   <td>GTS ?  
   </td>

        <td>
          <div class="col-md-10 columns">
          <ul id="GTSD" class="radio" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
          <label class="radio-inline" > <input type="radio" name="menu5" id = "menu5" value = "Yes">Yes</label>
          <label class="radio-inline" > <input type="radio" name="menu5" id = "menu5" value = "No">No</label>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </td>        
</tr>
```

I need to retrieve the value of this Radio button .
So I using this

```
$('#GTSD li').on('click', function(){
   $('#menu5').text($(this).text());
   $scope.dealQualification.menu5=$(this).text(); 
});
```

However I am not getting the value of selected radio button. Please let me know if anything wrong here or suggest some other way for the getting the value from above HTML descripton

Answer (score 0):

No need to do all this just mention ng-model attribute in input type radio and keep that attribute variable in controller's scope. Just take a look at the example:

```js
function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.selected = "NO";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" value="YES">YES
  <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" value="NO">NO

  <p>{{selected}}</p>
</div>
```